# Understanding tflite's quantization process

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, quantization

So I'm trying to Implement a CNN on C++ from scratch (without using stuff like tensorflow C API etc), with the end goal of converting it into verilog and running it on an FPGA. I managed to do it, and I'm able to succesfully run inference on a bunch of test examples. Now, in order to reduce memory usage, I tried out 8 bit integer only quantization (post training) using tflite. The quantization was successful, and I'm getting pretty good results. Now, I want to implement the network with the quantized weights on C++.

Before doing this, I wanted to do a proper analysis with the quantized weights, and verify all the computations, to understand the inference process completely and realize exactly what all goes into one forward pass. I used the `experimental_preserve_all_tensors=True` Flag for the tflite interpreter. I then invoked this on a uint8 array consisting of all values as 255. (The input shape is `(1,23,256,1)`). I then called `interpreter.invoke()` and saved all the tensors : i.e the weights, and also the outputs after every layer. (the first element of shape is the batch size)

Now, according to the saved data, the input is first converted to `int8` by subtracting 128. Then, this input is fed to a conv layer, which has 4 filters of shape `(1,8,1)` and 4 biases:

```
f1=[[-124, -104,  -57,  -68,  -14,  -64,  -17,  127]]

f2=[[-127,  -17,    9, -119,  109,  -72,   13, -112]]

f3=[[ 43,  71, 127,  73,  66,  33, -32,  15]]

f4=[[ -10,   33,  -61,  -73,  -94,  -60,  -99, -127]]

b= [-10, -24,   6,  -9]
```

It's trivial that convolution will result in a `(1,23,249,4)` array, i.e an array with 4 channels (which are 23 x 249 arrays). The values in a particular channel will all be the same, and they will be : `sum(f[i])*127 + b[i]`. So the 4 values should be : `-40777,-40156,50298,-62366`.

However, the model outputs after every layer have to be `int8`. tflite does something to bring this back to `int8` range, and I **am not able to figure out this process**. The values saved by the quantized model are `-63,-73,127,-128`. I have tried typecasting them into `np.int8`, and min-max normalization (with min=-128 and max =127), but they didn't work. I also visualized the model using netron, but I'm not able to make sense of the quantization values for this layer.

**How does tflite bring these values back to `int8` range?**